# WebSocket callback within arrow function not setting 'this' lexically

Tags: websocket, typescript, angular

I am trying to create a WebSocket service in Angular 2. Here is what I have so far:

```
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core"
@Injectable()
export class ServerService {

    public ws:WebSocket;

    public myData = {};

    constructor() {
        let ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/');

        ws.onopen = (event:Event) => {
            console.log("Socket has been opened!");
        };

        ws.onmessage = (event:Event) => {
            this.myData = JSON.parse(event.data);
        };
    };
}
```

The problem is, when `onmessage` runs, the `this` keyword becomes the WebSocket object, instead of my `ServerService` object.

It seems like my arrow function is acting as a standard function. What could be causing this? Is there another way to get back to the `ServerService` object?

Comment: Your code is fine, `this` will point to ServerService. [check the console on this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/xdnX78BbQvHItVQJpUYL?p=preview)

Comment: i think you are assigning `event.data` which is of type `WebSocket ` object may be thats the reason, try using console before assigning value in the `onmessage method`

Comment: how do you tell `this` keyword becomes the web socket object?

Comment: @BingLu it says so when I am debugging.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, so after seeing Abdulrahmans example working in plunk, I figured there was probably something wrong with my environment. Turns out my TypeScript was compiling to ES5, and was outputting:

```
function ServerService() {
                var _this = this;
                this.myData = {};
                var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
                ws.onopen = function (event) {
                    console.log("Socket has been opened!");
                };
                ws.onmessage = function (event) {
                    _this.myData = JSON.parse(event.data);
                };
            }
```

My arrow functions were indeed being removed, but replaced with something that should(?) be functionally equivalent. It works as expected in Firefox, but not in Chrome (which is where I was debugging).

I switched my TypeScript compiler to output ES6, and now I have arrow functions in my JavaScript, and my code works as expected in both browsers.

Comment: You save my day. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it using [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), which is only available on oldschool anonymous functions, not arrow functions.

So instead of:

```
ws.onmessage = (event:Event) => {
    this.myData = JSON.parse(event.data);
};
```

I did:

```
ws.onmessage = function(event:Event) {
    this.myData = JSON.parse(event.data);
}.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the websocket executed the callback in the context of the corresponding instance (with the `call` or `apply` method).

The work around consists of wrapping the websocket event handler into an observable:

```
initializeWebSocket(url) {
  this.wsObservable = Observable.create((observer) => {
    this.ws = new WebSocket(url);

    this.ws.onopen = (e) => {
      (...)
    };

    this.ws.onclose = (e) => {
      if (e.wasClean) {
        observer.complete();
      } else {
        observer.error(e);
      }
    };

    this.ws.onerror = (e) => {
      observer.error(e);
    }

    this.ws.onmessage = (e) => {
      observer.next(JSON.parse(e.data));
    }

    return () => {
      this.ws.close();
    };
  }).share();
}
```

This way you will be able to use arrow functions and the contextual this:

```
this.wsObservable.subscribe(data => {
  this.myData = data;
});
```

See this article for more details (section "Event-based support"):

- https://jaxenter.com/reactive-programming-http-and-angular-2-124560.html